# Parachain keeps trying to start collation over and over again, without success. But no Error or Panic occurred

Tags: parachain, relay-chain, substrate-parachain-template

I'm using the [Parity Tech Github](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot) as source for the Relay, with some simple modifications in the `node\service\src\chain_spec.rs` and `cli\src\command.rs` to build a personalized chain specification file.

So, I can input my seed(s) and it writes the keys and session keys in the `ChainSpec.json` file. After generating and transforming it to the raw format, I use the raw chain spec to add the keys into the node's keystore.

I'm using those 3 key types: gran, babe and imon.

```
./target/release/polkadot key insert --base-path /tmp/relay/multi1 --chain 3-raw.json --scheme ed25519 --suri "<key>" --key-type gran    
./target/release/polkadot key insert --base-path /tmp/relay/multi1 --chain 3-raw.json --scheme sr25519 --suri "<key>" --key-type babe
./target/release/polkadot key insert --base-path /tmp/relay/multi1 --chain 3-raw.json --scheme sr25519 --suri "<key>" --key-type imon
```

> I'm not using the Dev/Testing accounts. I'm using keys generated by me.

Everything on the Relay runs without any problems. The issue appears when I deploy a Parachain.
The Parachain Node is discovered, and can be seen as a FULL node on the Network>Node Info.

So, what I need to do? I have to add session keys for the parachain as well? If so, where?
What I'm missing here? Why it tries over and over to start collating but nothing happens?

[Output Log from the Parachain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDTrU.jpg)

```
2022-10-13 14:35:12.039  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #655 (0x7f2c…0759)
2022-10-13 14:35:12.043  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: Starting collation. relay_parent=0x88da0da170e12fe60447128581d6507e3faf82cdb355e3ea1d8cd7f22dc2d26e at=0x448337c11caa11ea07e126518e2c439e65b53e0ce223cf40ca040aa8d81a4800
2022-10-13 14:35:12.045  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: Starting collation. relay_parent=0x7f2ccf7c492abf73210caf96e1d280d4cfdce2ff310e7ad05f1bb12515500759 at=0x448337c11caa11ea07e126518e2c439e65b53e0ce223cf40ca040aa8d81a4800
2022-10-13 14:35:12.989  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x4483…4800), finalized #0 (0x4483…4800), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2022-10-13 14:35:13.112  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (2 peers), best: #655 (0x88da…d26e), finalized #652 (0xe496…e47e), ⬇ 1.2kiB/s ⬆ 0.5kiB/s
2022-10-13 14:35:17.989  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x4483…4800), finalized #0 (0x4483…4800), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2022-10-13 14:35:18.015 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::inclusion-inherent: [enter_inner] parent_header=0x88da0da170e12fe60447128581d6507e3faf82cdb355e3ea1d8cd7f22dc2d26e bitfields.len(): 0, backed_candidates.len(): 0, disputes.len(): 0
2022-10-13 14:35:18.016 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime: Batch-verification: 0 pending tasks, 0 sr25519 signatures
2022-10-13 14:35:18.016 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker runtime: Finalization of batch verification took 0 ms
2022-10-13 14:35:18.016 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::system: [656] length: 344 (normal 0%, op: 0%, mandatory 0%) / normal weight: 0 (0%) / op weight 0 (0%) / mandatory weight 6038475000 (0%)
2022-10-13 14:35:18.018  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #656 (0x3c1d…70da)
2022-10-13 14:35:18.021  INFO tokio-runtime-worker cumulus-collator: Starting collation. relay_parent=0x3c1d92f510cfb8ef59bd9eaf47734109f3cba6ce51981e749cdd40de9fc670da at=0x448337c11caa11ea07e126518e2c439e65b53e0ce223cf40ca040aa8d81a4800
```

---

Some additional info:

Error that appears when I try to do a Runtime call to generate session keys on the parachain ws.

```
 0: sp_panic_handler::set::{{closure}}
   1: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/std/src/panicking.rs:702:17
   2: std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/std/src/panicking.rs:588:13
   3: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:138:18
   4: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/std/src/panicking.rs:584:5
   5: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/core/src/panicking.rs:142:14
   6: core::panicking::panic_display
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/core/src/panicking.rs:72:5
   7: core::panicking::panic_str
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/core/src/panicking.rs:56:5
   8: core::option::expect_failed
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/core/src/option.rs:1874:5
   9: <&mut dyn sp_externalities::Externalities as sp_io::crypto::Crypto>::sr25519_generate_version_1
  10: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::with
  11: tracing::span::Span::in_scope
  12: sp_io::crypto::sr25519_generate_version_1
  13: sp_io::crypto::ExtCryptoSr25519GenerateVersion1::call
  14: <sc_executor_wasmtime::imports::Registry as sp_wasm_interface::HostFunctionRegistry>::with_function_context
  15: <core::panic::unwind_safe::AssertUnwindSafe<F> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<()>>::call_once
  16: <F as wasmtime::func::IntoFunc<T,(wasmtime::func::Caller<T>,A1,A2),R>>::into_func::wasm_to_host_shim
  17: <unknown>
  18: <unknown>
  19: wasmtime_runtime::traphandlers::catch_traps::call_closure
  20: wasmtime_setjmp
  21: wasmtime_runtime::traphandlers::catch_traps
  22: wasmtime::func::invoke_wasm_and_catch_traps
  23: sc_executor_wasmtime::instance_wrapper::EntryPoint::call
  24: sc_executor_wasmtime::runtime::perform_call
  25: <sc_executor_wasmtime::runtime::WasmtimeInstance as sc_executor_common::wasm_runtime::WasmInstance>::call
  26: sc_executor_common::wasm_runtime::WasmInstance::call_export
  27: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::with
  28: sc_executor::native_executor::WasmExecutor<H>::with_instance::{{closure}}
  29: sc_executor::wasm_runtime::RuntimeCache::with_instance
  30: <sc_executor::native_executor::NativeElseWasmExecutor<D> as sp_core::traits::CodeExecutor>::call
  31: sp_state_machine::execution::StateMachine<B,H,Exec>::execute_aux
  32: sp_state_machine::execution::StateMachine<B,H,Exec>::execute_using_consensus_failure_handler
  33: <sc_service::client::call_executor::LocalCallExecutor<Block,B,E> as sc_client_api::call_executor::CallExecutor<Block>>::call
  34: <sc_rpc::state::state_full::FullState<BE,Block,Client> as sc_rpc::state::StateBackend<Block,Client>>::call
  35: <tokio::runtime::blocking::task::BlockingTask<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
  36: tokio::runtime::task::core::CoreStage<T>::poll
  37: tokio::runtime::task::harness::Harness<T,S>::poll
  38: tokio::runtime::blocking::pool::Inner::run
  39: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace
  40: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}
  41: <alloc::boxed::Box<F,A> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<Args>>::call_once
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:1951:9
      <alloc::boxed::Box<F,A> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<Args>>::call_once
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:1951:9
      std::sys::unix::thread::Thread::new::thread_start
             at /rustc/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/library/std/src/sys/unix/thread.rs:108:17
  42: start_thread
  43: clone
Thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'No keystore associated for the current context!', /home/amrm/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/e8a7d16/primitives/io/src/lib.rs:846
```

Thanks for any hint or help in advance! x)

Comment: Hello Alexandre, maybe you are from the blockchain academy if so its me Ramsey, hello! A good tip is to rotateKeys so that al the keys in your node's keystore are added then setKeys on the chain. There are probably somekeys missing so that parachain functionality can work. Check this tutorial which has the rotateKeys workflow https://decentration.medium.com/set-up-public-relay-validators-with-a-partner-3ef409c675c7

Comment: Aslo are you running with just one validator on the relay chain? you need at least 3 validators in order to include a parachain.

Comment: Also in the error it says `No keystore associated for the current context!` try adding --alice and --bob to your collator commands, which should add the keys to the keystore of your nodes automatically. But if your chain spec of your parachain requires specific keys then you will need add those keys, to do that you need to curl insertKey with the correct methods. Or do key-insert like you did with the relay chain.

Answer (score 2):

In the error it says `No keystore associated for the current context!`

This means that your parachain node does not have the aura key that it needs to start collating.

Try adding `--alice` and `--bob` to your collator commands e.g. (./target/release/parachain-collator --collator --alice...`), which should add the keys to the keystore of your nodes automatically.

But if you have added specific keys to the chain spec of your parachain node then you will need add those keys, just like you did with `key-insert` for your relay chain.

Or you can make a curl request:

`curl -vH 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{ "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"author_insertKey", "params":["aura", "0x153d8db5f7ef35f18a456c049d6f6e2c723d6c18d1f9f6c9fbee880c2a171c73", "0x408f99b525d90cce76288245cb975771282c2cefa89d693b9da2cdbed6cd9152"],"id":1 }' localhost:9933`

Comment: Yes, I'm using specific keys for both. In the Relay and in the Parachain. The thing is, how can I add those keys to the parachain keystore?
The parachain build doesn't have the key subcommand. When I tried using the Relay binary to use it's `key-insert` I got a panic error. (rethinking now, it might work! )   
Can I add the key subcommand in the cli.rs and commands.rs on my para node?
And thanks for the help!! <3 I'll try to add it to the para's keystore.

Comment: Yes, as I thought the error when trying to insert the keys into the parachain keystore returns me this:

./target/release/polkadot key insert --base-path /tmp/parachain/mld --chain rococo-para-2000-raw.json --scheme sr25519 --suri "<key>" --key-type aura

Error:
   0: Invalid input: Error parsing spec file: unknown field relay_chain at line 64 column 1
Backtrace omitted. Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display it.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.

Comment: Then you can curl it in something like this: curl -vH 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{ "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"author_insertKey", "params":["aura", "0x153d8db5f7ef35f18a456c049d6f6e2c723d6c18d1f9f6c9fbee880c2a171c73", "0x408f99b525d90cce76288245cb975771282c2cefa89d693b9da2cdbed6cd9152"],"id":1 }' localhost:9933

Comment: Still don't working.  When I'm going to check the node's keystore by `ls /tmp/parachain/mycol` it shows two chain options instead of just one. Can you please check if that is correct? [terminal outputs](https://imgur.com/a/5XB6jdD)

Comment: When I tried the curl, the output I got was `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":null,"id":1}` I must be missing something on the keystore. I'm going crazy with this D:

Comment: That means success. I know that’s a confusing result, but that is expected. There is docs on this somewhere.

Comment: The result null means there’s no error when inserting the key. You can check the keystore file in your directory where ever you added the —base-path (e.g. /home/…/parachain/keystore) and you will see the key in there.

Comment: Yes, indeed it works. But what happens after I insert the key is.
2022-10-17 14:25:47.587  WARN tokio-runtime-worker parachain::collator-protocol: Collation wasn't advertised to any validator. candidate_hash=0xe5c94d1cada5991c78b2ba39adf80aa90c96e085897beede55ac0f3241745075 pov_hash=0x0c8955bdc0f991fc543f8dcec038ecdb8ef445842a795ff5205265b95f0299c9 traceID=305438426720980369332937585534051027625

Comment: whenever i get that warning i am usually on the wrong branch. So i need to make sure i have checkout and compiled the correct branch.